# Sort a Collection of POJOs based on a List of integers

Tags: java, sorting, collections

So,

I have a situation where I use a list of Integers to fetch some data from different sources. As a result, I get two Lists, both have the same POJOs Type as content and include exactly all of the elements from my input list, however in an unknown order.

What I need is to get these POJOs sorted in the same order as my first list (this Integer is a field with getter/setter in the POJO), so I get a List with POJOs in exactly the same order as my Integer list.

So, the steps I'm thinking of are:

1. Join the two POJO lists into one, so I at least have 2 identically sized lists (Integer and POJO) that I know contain matching elements.
2. Sort the resulting POJO list to match the Integer list.

However, for step 2 I need to find the good (that means, efficient and neat) way to do it... I am thinking of creating a Comparator somewhat like this:

```
public class POJOComparable implements Comparator<MyPOJO>{

  private List<Integer> values;

  public POJOComparable(List<Integer> values) {
    this.values = values;
  } 

  @Override
  public int compare(MyPOJO o1P, MyPOJO o2P) {
      int o1 = values.indexOf(o1P.getId());
      int o2 = values.indexOf(o2P.getId());
      return (o1>o2 ? -1 : (o1==o2 ? 0 : 1));
  }
}
```

Now, is this a good approach to do such a sorting or is there some nicer or more efficient way to do it? The lists will be of about 20 items, but this sorting will be performed quite often so I'm looking for the efficient way to do it.

Comment: Store the values of your `List<MyPojo>` in a `TreeMap<Integer, MyPojo>` and let that this collection do the sorting for you.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have a `List<Integer>` and a `List<Pojo>` and you want to match the elements? Or just sort the `List<Pojo>`?

Comment: Well, have to say, the List<Integer> could contain something like this: (5, 7, 2, 35, 21, 78, 1), being this the right order I would expect for the TreeMap, If I wanted to store the index of the first Collection in the TreeMap, I would still have to construct the TreeMap with the values from the first List. Would that still be more efficient than my approach?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, the idea is to match the order of both lists. In the POJO I have an Integer field that matches a value of the Integer List, however my Integer List has a different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is expensive, it takes `O(nlgn)`. I would say use a `Map` to map the `Pojo`s by id and then retrieve them from the `Map` in the `List` order. This takes a little more memory but should be faster:

```
    final Map<Integer, Pojo> pojoMap = new HashMap<>(pojos.size(), 1f);
    for (final Pojo pojo : pojos) {
        pojoMap.put(pojo.id, pojo);
    }

    final List<Pojo> sortedPojos = new ArrayList<>(ids.size());
    for (final int id : ids) {
        sortedPojos.add(pojoMap.get(id));
    }
```

So

1. Loop over the `Pojo`s and create a `Map` by the property.
2. Loop over the original `List` and populate a new `List` by looking up the `Pojo`s in the `Map`.

Comment: Well, since I like to confirm answers in practice and not only in theory, I measured times with System.nanoTime() on a list of over 500 elements. Your solution averages about 278000 nanoseconds, the one from Luiggi 2111000, so your solution in practice was 8 times faster on a much bigger list than I will be using. I think I could use both approaches and it will be fine for the small lists (20 elements instead of 507), however I really prefer to control what type of List I get as an output and it's always better to go the more efficient way. Thank you both for the effort!

Comment: Note: even on the 20 elements list, it is at least twice as fast, so it can really be confirmed that it is O(n) and the other one was O(n^2). With the Collection framework it is just sometimes not so easy to see, you must really trust the implementation and have knowledge of how each Collection processes...

Answer (score 4):

Store the values of your `List<MyPojo>` in a `TreeMap<Integer, MyPojo>` and let that this collection do the sorting for you. A simple way to accomplish this would be:

```
TreeMap<Integer, MyPojo> aSortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, MyPojo>();
for(MyPojo pojo : aListOfMyPojo) {
    aSortedMap.put(values.indexOf(pojo.getId()), pojo);
}
```

Note that this approach assumes that every `pojo.getId()` has a single unique value inside `List<Integer> values`.

---

Based on @BoristheSpider comment, instead of having a `List<Integer> values` and seek each value of `pojo.getId()` using `List#indexOf`, it would be better using a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where you store the value of `pojo.getId()` and the desired `Integer` value to accelerate the searching process. So, the resultant algorithm should look like this:

```
//replace the List<Integer> by a Map<Integer>
Map<Integer, Integer> values = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
//store the pojo.getId() value with its associated int value
values.put(pojo.getId(), ...);

//...
TreeMap<Integer, MyPojo> aSortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, MyPojo>();
for(MyPojo pojo : aListOfMyPojo) {
    aSortedMap.put(values.get(pojo.getId()), pojo);
}
```

Comment: OK, seems like a good way to do it. Seems like I only call the indexOf for the elements once, so it should be a better way than using the Comparator...

Comment: This is pretty horrible. `indexof` is `O(n)` for a `List` so this whole thing is `O(n^2)` where it should be `O(n)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider but that's how OP wants/needs to do the sorting. Note that `values.indexOf(pojo.getId())` can return `10` while `pojo.getId()` returns `0`.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's why I suggested using a `Map` to index the pojos by id for lookup later. That method is `O(n)` as `put` and `get` are `O(1)` for a `HashMap`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider based on your approach, instead of `Map<Integer, Pojo>` it should be `Map<Integer, Integer>`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well, Pros and cons of both solutions... Luiggis approach only involves creating one loop, but inside it it has to make a nested loop for each element. BoristheSpider suggests two loops which will iterate each only once and use the HashMap to do a more efficient find. The main advantage on Luigis approach is that I get two Lists that I can control how they are built without extra effort... Will test them both out and see what happens...

Comment: @Martin a nested loop is `O(n^2)` which increases with the square of the number of times. Two loops is `O(n)`. This is a **massive** difference! Take a look at [this](http://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=x&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=x^2&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=0&x_max=30&y_min=0&y_max=900&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525), blue line is `x=x` and red line is `x=x^2`.

Comment: Gave BoristheSpider the right answer. I made a list in my Unit Test with more than 500 entries and tested the sorting with both methods. The code from BoristheSpider was in average 8 times faster in the 4 runs I did, so I'll keep that approach. Thank you both for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Change the POJO class to include the index as an int. If you only have order tens of objects at a time, the wasted space is trivial. The gain is simplicity, directness, and reduced risk of confusion.

The Comparator just looks at a field in each object - no expensive list searches.

Comment: Sorry, can't do that, the Pojo is generated on another layer so I don't have the index value at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer, first sort both lists independently and then merge them together, comparing the first elements of both lists each time you iterate (using your comparator). This is the most efficient way.

You can sort both lists with the default java sorting.

Comment: Just as a question, this approach would be using the Comparator I am building? For the merge, what would you use?

Comment: a simple self-written loop that checks which of the first elements has the smallest value. This is how merge-sorting works.